# Processing just HTML fragment and returning it

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When I do the following with Nokogiri:

```
some_html = '<img src="bleh.jpg"/>test<br/>'
f = Nokogiri::HTML(some_html)
#do some processing
puts f
```

It will print the whole XHTML doc structure with the upper code in it.

How can I just print/return/get the html part which is in `some_html` variable?

---

No.

`f` will return:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www
.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<img src=\"bleh.jpg\">test<br>\n
</body></html>\n"
```

I only want the inner/fragment part:

```
<img src=\"bleh.jpg\">test<br>
```

Answer (score 38):

Instead of parsing using `Nokogiri::HTML(...)` use `Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(...)`:

```
asdf = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment('<img src="bleh.jpg">test<br>')
print asdf.to_html
# >> <img src="bleh.jpg">test<br>
```

Comment: it's a matter of style, but personally I find Nokogiri::HTML.fragment less confusing than Nokogiri::HTML::fragment - it does not look like a typo ;)

Comment: Ruby styleguides recommend to use `.` instead of `::` for calling class methods, so `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment` is obviously preferred.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the 'html' part?

Just do `f.text()` to get the inner text.